# How to get form input values in tabbed forms

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

A minimal example demonstrating the question:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title='Dashboard'),
  dashboardSidebar(    
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem('Dashboard', tabName='dashboard', icon=icon('dashboard'))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = 'dashboard',
        fluidRow(
          tabBox(
            id='dashboard_tabs',
            tabPanel(
              title='Tab 1',
              uiOutput('tab1Content')
            ),
            tabPanel(
              title='Tab 2',
              uiOutput('tab2Content')
            ),
            width=8
          ),
          box(
            title='Input summary',
            uiOutput('summary'),
            width=4
          )
        ),
        actionButton('update', 'Update summary')
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  state <- reactiveValues(
    input1=NULL,
    input2=NULL
  )

  observeEvent(input$update, {
    state$input1 <- input$input1
    state$input2 <- input$input2
  })

  output$summary <- renderUI({
    shiny::tags$ul(
      shiny::tags$li(
        strong('Input 1: '),
        state$input1
      ),
      shiny::tags$li(
        strong('Input 2: '),
        state$input2
      )
    )
  })

  output$tab1Content <- renderUI(
    textInput('input1', 'Input 1', value=1)
  )

  output$tab2Content <- renderUI(
    textInput('input2', 'Input 2', value=2)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If one runs this example and clicks the 'Update' button, the summary box (right) only shows a value for 'Input 1'. This does not happen if the form is not tabbed or if the inputs are directly rendered at ui instead via uiOutput+renderUI, so this seems kind of bad behaviour with both tabs and uiOutput.

So then, what's the way to get input values from tabbed forms if tabs are rendered via renderUI *before* navigating to those tabs?

**EDIT1**: Fixed typo in sample code.
**EDIT2**: Sample code showing the real problem, last version didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Ther is an error in your code, in the sedcond tab, you should write :

```
textInput('input2', 'Input 2', value=2)
```

and not

```
textInput('input1', 'Input 2', value=2)
```

**After typo correction**

So,could this be a solution for you :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title='Dashboard'),
  dashboardSidebar(    
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem('Dashboard', tabName='dashboard', icon=icon('dashboard'))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = 'dashboard',
              fluidRow(uiOutput("ui")
                ,
                box(
                  title='Input summary',
                  uiOutput('summary'),
                  width=4
                )
              ),
              actionButton('update', 'Update summary')
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  state <- reactiveValues(
    input1=1,
   input2=2
  ) 

  observeEvent(input$update, {
    state$input1 <- input$input1
    state$input2 <- input$input2
  })

  output$summary <- renderUI({
    shiny::tags$ul(
      shiny::tags$li(
        strong('Input 1: '),
        state$input1
      ),
      shiny::tags$li(
        strong('Input 2: '),
        state$input2
      )
    )
  })


  output$ui <- renderUI({

  tabBox(
    id='dashboard_tabs',
tabPanel(
  title='Tab 1',
  uiOutput('tab1Content'), textInput('input1', 'Input 1', value=1)
),
tabPanel(
  title='Tab 2',
  uiOutput('tab2Content'),textInput('input2', 'Input 2', value=2)
),
    width=8
  )

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Edited the question to show the real problem... As you say sample code i posted before fails because of a typo, not because of the problem i tried to show.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... It works because when output$ui gets rendered then all tabs render at once, thing that doesn't happen if each tab is in its own uiOutput(), which is what i asked.

Comment: So my question really happens to be: Is it possible to force a ui content to be rendered if not visible? It doesn't seem to be an option for this... I'll keep this question opened for some time, but i think there's no solution not consisting in hacks of some kind.